# Script which would run a line of code then wait for answer then write another one in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to write a simple script which would run a two different lines of code that I already know. If that wasn't really clear, let me give an example.
For example, i'd like to make a script which, when executed, would run "Start-Process notepad" in powershell, then wait for it to output something, and then run "Remove-Item E:\Folder1\Test.txt"

Thanks in advance

I looked up my question on google but didn't find any answer, maybe i didn't formulate my question well enough.

Comment: If you want to make the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call _synchronous_ (blocking until Notepad exits), add the `-Wait` switch. Most PowerShell commands and external programs run synchronously by default. Also note that `Start-Process` produces no output, unless you add `-PassThru`, in which case you get an object _describing the launched process_ - not what the process itself outputs.

Comment: My question wasn't  exactly that, sorry if  my formulation wasn't clear. The two lines of code I wanted to run were "spicetify backup", wait until it outputs, then run "spicetify backup restore apply" and what I'd like to have would just be a script that would run this in powershell when it's executed

Comment: Then put these two statements in a script file (`*.ps1`), each on its own line.